# Switch between classes which implement a same interface

Tags: java

Let's say I have this code.

```
public interface A {
    public boolean move();
}

public class B implements A {
    public boolean move() {
        // do some stuff
        // return true
    }
}

public class C implements A {
    public boolean move() {
        // don't do anything
        // return false
    }
}
```

Can I do something like this?

```
B cell = new B();
// move() method will return True and will do some stuff
// now I'd like to change the B cell to C cell
// move() method will return False and won't do anything
```

Thanks for any help!

I hope the code should be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to use the interface (A) instead

```
A cell = new B();
//or
//A cell = new C();
```

Comment: OK, let's say I do `A cell = new B();`. Can I do `cell = C()` later?

Comment: The only real question to ask is whether `C` is an `A`? If so then it can be assigned as one.

Comment: @JohnDoe you need to do `cell = new C();`